# Find Sequential week counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table

```
PLAN_DATA
[username],[workdate],[pid]
```

I want to find the sequential weeks, which are filled with PID=12.
I am trying the below query for the expected result

[image]

```
select username,DATEPART(w,workdate),DATEPART(m,workdate),pid 
from plan_data where username='peter' and YEAR(workdate)=2018 
and pid=12
group by username,DATEPART(w,workdate),DATEPART(m,workdate),pid
```

The table will contain data for 52 weeks with different PIDs.
I want to get the result like above format with PIDs = 12, that is the sequential weeks occurrences more than 3 times. 
PIDs 12 filled continuously for some weeks have to tracked

Comment: And what result do you want?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I want to get only the list of week values which are continuous weeks for the PIDs 12
The continuous week numbers (like 2,3,4 or 12,13,14,15,16, or ...)
I have edited my question too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group the sequential weeks together?

You could use a trick with difference between row_number and week, something like this:

```
select *, w - RN from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by m order by w asc) as RN
    from(
        select username,DATEPART(w,workdate) as w,DATEPART(m,workdate) as m,pid 
        from plan_data where username='peter' and YEAR(workdate)=2018 
        and pid=12
        group by username,DATEPART(w,workdate),DATEPART(m,workdate),pid
    ) X
) Y
```

Depending on what you want to do, then apply group by w-RN, min/max etc for this data.

Comment: If the month isn't related to the sequencies, and it doesn't seem to be because you have same group for more than 5 weeks, remove the partition by -- and you might want to partition by pid, username etc. in reality

Comment: Thanks for the answer; But the query not running
`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'X'.`

Comment: sorry, there's no comma before order by in the syntax. Can't test anything now :)

Comment: Its running, In my question I want to get the PID occurrence if it is in more than 3 continuous weeks; but the answer gets even its in one weeks

Comment: You added that to the question afterwards. It's really unclear "PID occurence" means, if you want the count of weeks that are sequential, and only show numbers over 3, then just group by with `w-RN` add a count(*) and remove anything under 3

Comment: Sorry for that; I will try your answer

Comment: I tried your query, Its not working as expected: It returns result even the weeks are not sequential.

For one of the user getting week list like (2,3,6); Its not sequential

Comment: It returns everything. There is no where clause. Look at the data it returns and make the necessary rules based on the groups (w-RN).